# Export Term Store and GUIDs without using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server

I need to export my term store with the GUIDs but do not have access to the administration area so cannot use the Powershell method.  Is there another way of doing it?

I need to know as I have a catalogue with managed metadata columns and I tend to input all the information into an excel sheet and then copy and paste it into the quick edit datasheet in SharePoint 2013.

If I want this to work with the managed metadata, I have to include the GUID.  I’ve created a drop down list in excel so I can choose the terms I want to include, but my term store is getting larger, so if I could export all the terms with GUIDs that would be super helpful.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is feasible without the admin access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSOM, which does not require admin access. I don't have code for you but you can certainly extract taxonomy - including GUIDs - via CSOM.